# question about normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I'm not being able to identify the mathematical pattern used answer this question:

Suppose that the length of a speficic kind of snake may  be modelled by a normal distribution with mean 50.8 (cm) and standard deviation 0.8.

Calculate the length (cm) that is exceeded by only 7% of this specific kind of snake.

What I though:

- Plot the C.D.F and find the 93th percentile (maybe using z-score)?. is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Find the $\text{z-score}$ of where the CDF is 0.93. In this case, the value is $1.48$. Knowing the Z-score to be $1.48$, perform standardization.

You will get, letting $X$ to be the length of a randomly chosen snake, we attempt to find
$$ P(X>x) = 0.7$$
Which turns out
$$1.48 = \frac {x - \mu}{\sigma}$$

so
$$x = 1.48(0.8) + {50.8} = 51.98\text {cm}$$

Z-table link is [here](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~dinov/courses_students.dir/STAT10_Fall01/STAT10_Fall01/z-table.JPG).

Comment: In other words, you can say that, if you randomly pick a snake, 7% of the time it is greater than 51.98cm.<br/>